# Conversion to APFS vs. reformatting

Tags: apfs, file-conversion

Wanting to convert an external HFS+ drive to APFS.  This is said to be doable without losing the current content.  I have no reason to doubt that.  But I'm curious:

**Is there any reason (any significant difference) to instead do a fresh erase/reformat?  (and then restore the contents from backup)**

Comment: Is there a reason for the conversion?  Is the external drive an SSD?  If not,  you’re not likely to see any benefit from doing this.  HFS+ is still a solid partition scheme especially for external drives.

Comment: Also, [see this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393587/119271) on what happens during the conversion process.  It is a “format in place” so there’s no difference.

Comment: A real reason to do it is for Volume support, regardless of SSD or spinning disk. You also get improved Time Machine if you're using it for backups.

Comment: Not using it for backups.  For very large libraries that do not change often.  So the APFS trick of re-using identical blocks might save a tiny bit of space.